# Facing the following error: E: Unable to locate package python-empy

Tags: python, linux, px4

I am trying to install the toolchain for building Px4 on Linux.

I am facing the following error when I am giving the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-argparse git-core wget zip \ python-empy qtcreator cmake build-essential
```

> E: Unable to locate package  python-empy

Log:

```
neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install python-argparse git-core wget zip \ python-empy qtcreator cmake build-essential genromfs -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpython2.7-stdlib' instead of 'python-argparse'
E: Unable to locate package  python-empy
neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-argparse git-core wget zip python-empy qtcreator cmake build-essential -y
```

The problem is you are using the back slash "/" wrong. It is used for the target release.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above.. quick ques : Is it not required to give the below command if I have done the ur suggested solution ?                       "sudo apt-get install python-argparse git-core wget zip \ python-empy qtcreator cmake build-essential genromfs -y"

Comment: So, what happend? @NeeleshI

Comment: It worked ... But I am still facing the error when I give the mentioned command..Thank you for ur quick reply

Comment: Different ways to do the same, I just wanted to check if the package you are trying to install you can download it, because I could. Did you try separate?

Comment: So, you could install all the package! great! so, what's your other question?

Comment: Separate means like this??                                                                  neelesh@neelesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ python-empy qtcreator cmake build-essential genromfs -y
python-empy: command not found

Comment: No no, your problem is with the back slash "/", this is used for the target release, if you erese it everything work, I will update the answer so you can see

Comment: Got It..Yea it helped thank you ... Only thing is why is it showing "python-empy: command not found" even though I have installed it??...

Comment: Awesome bro ... I dont know about backslash...I have tried it without it Now it is not showing that error .. Thank you!!

Comment: Try run the complete command of the answer, still telling you the error?

Comment: No problem! I have always loved to help :)

Comment: Don't forget voting if that helps, now you can ;) congrats

Comment: Yea ... Sure :)